# pass data from table to modal using angular

Tags: spring, angular, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Im using Spring MVC and AngularJS to build my app and I been looking for a way to pass a table registry data to a modal in order to edit that registry but I haven´t find a working example so, thats my question how can a I pass the registry data to a modal?
This is what I have so far:
Table

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                                <thead class="table-striped">
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Apellidos</th>
                                <th>Rol</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr data-ng-show="allUsuarios.length === 0">
                                        <td colspan="4" class="warning">No hay registros para mostrar</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr data-ng-repeat="usuarios in allUsuarios">
                                        <td>{{usuarios.email}}</td>
                                        <td>{{usuarios.nombre}}</td>
                                        <td>{{usuarios.apellidos}}</td>
                                        <td>{{usuarios.idRol.tipoRol}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="hidden" value="{{usuarios.idUsuario}}"/>
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModalEditar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModalEliminar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

And the Modal:

```
<!--EDIT MODAL-->
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="modal fade" id="formModalEditar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="H2">Editar Usuario</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <form role="form" action="add" method="post">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Email</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required=""/>
                                                    <label>Nombre</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required=""/>
                                                    <label>Apellidos</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required=""/>
                                                    <label>Rol</label>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <div class="btn-group open">
                                                        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="text-right">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--END EDIT MODAL-->
```

PS: I don´t know why when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to format the code, it gets displayed like that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to define a registery in you angular component

```
currentRegistery : Registery;
```

In your table you have to add an onclick on the edit icon of each registery to be able to set the current Registery with the selected registery

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModalEditar" onclick=“currentRegistery=usuarios”><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
```

Finally on your modal you can deal directly with the currentRegistery object.